# defining interface

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a datamodel used by multiple application that I now needs to be used by other developers outside the team. The model should only be made partialy available to the developers.

I wonder how I best approach this: my current approach is to create a new project that just copies the orginal model and only include the requested properties.

for example

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Car
    {
        private double m_speed;
        private FuelType m_fuelType;

        public double Speed
        {
            get { return m_speed; }
            set { m_speed = value; }
        }       


        public FuelType FuelType
        {
            get { return m_fuelType; }
            set { m_fuelType = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Lite Model I only want to expose the speed:

```
using Model;

namespace ModelLite
{
    public class Car
    {
        private Model.Car car = new Model.Car();

        public double Speed
        {
            get { return this.car.Speed; }
            set { this.car.Speed = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Since the model is big this involves in a lot of duplication. Maybe there is a better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the work by Martin Fowler on [Application Facades](http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/appfacades.pdf) and the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: I think the link for Application Facades should be http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/appfacades.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution to this problem. If different devs are only allowed to have partial access to fields, you will need to create different feeds for different devs.

---

Although your model just seems wrong to me, you might however accomplish this by:

- Creating one feed object that has all the properties the main object also has
- Create some attribute like:

---

```
 class FeedSecurityAttribute : Attribute  
 {   
       public FeedSecurityAttribute(params string[] rights) {}  
 }
```

---

- Add annotations on the properties of the feed specifying who has access to this property like `[FeedSecurity("piet", "klaas")] string MyProperty { get;set; }`
- Fill your feed object from a business object automatically using some reflection and expression trees, and check whether the user has access to the property, otherwise ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You could may be look at using multiple interfaces

```
public interface ICarBasic
{
    double Speed { get; set; }
}

public interface ICar : ICarBasic
{
    FuelType FuelType { get; set; } 
}
```

Or Write all your Basic object as base classes. Inherit from them to make the full classes using a new assembly.  Giving the developers out side the project only the assembly with the base classes in might solv your issue.

Assembly 1 (For the other Devs)

```
using Model;         

namespace ModelLite         
{         
    public class Car         
    {         
        private Model.Car car = new Model.Car();         

        public double Speed         
        {         
            get { return this.car.Speed; }         
            set { this.car.Speed = value; }         
        }         

    }         
}
```

Assembly 2 (Fully Featured)

```
using ModelLite

namespace Model          
{          
    public class Car : ModelLite.Car         
    {          
        private FuelType m_fuelType;          

        public FuelType FuelType          
        {          
            get { return m_fuelType; }          
            set { m_fuelType = value; }          
        }          
    }          
}
```

Only give assembly 1 to the other developers.

Comment: This is basically what Tarscher says in his first post. This is unmaintainable when you'll need to support this for > X different feed versions.

Comment: The original post was the other way around. He was implementing speed twice. My suggestion only has it once. And since when has Inheritence been unmaintainable?

Comment: It's unmaintainable if you have `class Car { Model; Year; Fuel; }` and want to expose `Model; Year;` to one person, `Fuel; Model;` to another, and `Year; Fuel;` to someone else.